# Looking for .NET Winforms equivalent of HTML table

Tags: .net, winforms

I work in a `.NET` shop that is focused primarily on a web application. There are, however, a few integral parts of our software that are `Winform` (the application itself serves up the web pieces via a browser control, but is otherwise used for very little). I don't have much experience with `Winforms` (except fixing the occasional business logic bug). Primarily, I work on the web. However, my current task has me adding a major piece of functionality to our `Winform` application, under the constraints of a **highly abbreviated development cycle**. The sooner I can slap together an **alpha version**, the better.

Without going into all of the project details and the specs of the new feature, what I really need is something that is the **equivalent of an HTML table**. Keep in mind, I do not need something that just binds to a datatable. I need whatever container is used to hold a variety of controls of varying types in each "cell" or "panel", and the number of "rows" and "columns" need to be variable. It'll be displayed inside of a `RadPanel` that will pop up in front of the normal form and then, after the user performs their interactions, be hidden; I'll use the result of their interaction further along in the process (that piece is already written).

From what I've read in the past, this sort of thing is relatively easy with `WPF`, however I'm stuck using `Winforms` on it for now. Can anyone suggest a control that fits the bill? I've considered a `TableLayoutPanel`, however I'd hate to get a mile down the road, just to find out that for some reason it won't work (due to either scalability, lack of theming support, etc.). Likewise I've considered a `DataGridView`, but my (admittedly cursory) investigation suggests there are a lot of complications involved in that particular route. I'm sure it's a relatively simple matter to do this with `Winforms` - I just don't have an unlimited amount of time to scour the documentation and experiment with a dozen different possibilities.

Any informed suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: DataGridView sounds simple enough for the reqs, but that's experience I guess.  What scares you off it?  I would rather do Crono1981's suggested answer of nest WPF though as this is ideal for it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard The problem I see with a `TableLayoutPanel` is that I need an effective way to link data in, say, column 3 row 5 with the object that data came from - and the `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't provide for any sort of easy linking to the object it's populated from. I'd have to handle the binding by hand, which, while doable (possibly within a hidden column that holds an object identifier), is rather tedious. I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: @bland It's primarily that what I've read indicates you have to do quite a bit of the plumbing yourself, and I'm an a time crunch on this. If that's the route best suited, I can do so. It could be that it's as simple as handling the binding on a `gridview` in `Webforms` - I just don't know, having never done it before.

Comment: If you like how databinding works in ASP.NET, you'll definitely want to have a look on how it's done in XAML. It's magical. Feels like unicorn eating honey crumbs right off your hand in a farm high up on a cloud.

Comment: @Blorgbeard If you want to add `TableLayoutPanel` as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Added. I wondered why you were considering FlowLayoutPanel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx). It's reasonably flexible regarding row/column sizing, and supports spanning controls across multiple rows/columns.

Comment: Careful with this. If you want one control per cell, you may choke your application. Remember that one control = one window handle registered in the system, with everything that comes with it: message subscribing, memory usage, etc. This won't scale well if many rows or columns are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since time is an issue, you should consider looking into a 3rd party grid control. If you are a quick learner and don't mind the extra dependency, that would be perfect. It won't cost nearly as much as doing something similar all by yourself, it will already be thought for reusing and it will provide you with extra features like **grouping, filtering, ordering and printing**. You may not need that right away, but it will be there when you do.

Otherwise you don't have many (good) options left here. You could nest WPF within your Winform Form / Control or use a clever combination of GDI+ painting and dynamic, on-cell control creation technique.

If you are absolutely certain that you won't ever have over about a hundred **ACTIVE** controls in the whole table at a time (which is already a lot IMHO), then you could consider creating all controls dynamically. It's easier than going down the windowless path, but **it won't scale well**. Keep in mind that **there's a limit on how much active controls a Windows application can contain** at a time. If the plan is to have something you can reuse, you will not want to do that.

Comment: In case you wonder: Winform grid controls (properly conceived) provides the illusion that there's a lot of controls in the screen. But the truth is that they're only painted. They are created only when cells are activated and they're destroyed as soon as they lose focus. So the limit on numbers of active controls isn't an issue anymore. At most, a grid might have 4 of 5 live controls at the same time, for things like scrollbars, the currently activated cell, and of course the grid control itself.

Comment: Oh and the TableLayoutPanel is not to be mistaken for a grid control. Every control you put in it, either at design or runtime, will be active.